# How to convert chrome.storage.sync.get to browser.storage.sync.get? (or, how to use Promises)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to port an extension but my JS is very rusty.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities says The equivalent WebExtensions APIs use promises instead:

Original:

```
    var read = function(name, deflt) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve){
                    chrome.storage.sync.get([name], function(result){
                            if (chrome.runtime.lastError)
                                    throw new Error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
                            resolve(result[name] || deflt);
                    }); 
            });
    };
```

I feel there should be a very simple and nice solution to this because the code should return a promise and `browser.storage.sync.get` also happens to return a promise already... I just don't know how.

Answer (score 3):

Since `browser.storage.sync.get` returns a Promise (and assuming the signature is the same as the chrome version), something like this should be equivalent. This returns a Promise immediately, which you can call `then()` and `catch()` on to handle success and error cases respectively

```
var read = function(name, deflt) {
  return browser.storage.sync.get([name])
    .then(result => {
      if (browser.runtime.lastError) { // assuming this exists
        throw new Error(browser.runtime.lastError);
      }

      return result[name] || deflt
    })          
};

read('foo', 'barDefault')
  .then(doStuffWithResult)
  .catch(console.error)
```

Comment: Thanks ` .then(result => result[name] || deflt)    ` is the syntax I was very much unsure about -- but since this is a library function putting the error inside as in the original would be nice. Or is that default behavior now that `lastError` is not used?

Comment: @chx updated the code here to account for the error, which appears to just "exist" out of band attached to the runtime with this API (so it's not automatically thrown). I'm not super familiar with the API to know if the WebExtensions API is equivalent here, but if it is this should work the same. Errors in either case are expected to be caught/handled by the caller.